Magento 2 save admin integration it shows 404 error: Page not found
We are using magento version 2.4.6-p3 when we are trying to save admin integration it shows 404 error: Page not found.
We can save Design configuration,product,categories but 404 error only coming when save admin integration


Module Registration Issues

Make sure your module is properly registered by checking if you have the registration.php file in the module directory.
Verify that the module.xml file is correct, and the module is enabled by running:
php bin/magento module:status
If the module is disabled, enable it using:
php bin/magento module:enable Vendor_Module
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Clear Cache

Clear Magento's cache to ensure the routing changes take effect:
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush

Check Admin Route Configuration

Ensure that your admin routes are correctly defined in your routes.xml:
<router id="admin">
    <route id="vendor_module" frontName="vendor_module">
        <module name="Vendor_Module" />
    </route>
</router>


ACL Permissions

A 404 error can occur if the user does not have permission to access the page. Ensure your acl.xml is properly configured:



Then assign this permission to the user roles that need access.

Reindexing

Sometimes reindexing can help resolve issues:
php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Correct URL Structure

Double-check the URL structure in the admin panel. The URL should follow the correct format: https://example.com/adminname/frontname/controller/action

Run Compilation and Deployment

If you are in production mode, run the following commands:
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
